# CSS - Force table to stay on the page

Tags: html, css

On some mobile devices such as iPhone 5C my tables on my web page are half way off the page. How can I change that so my page width will not get any smaller than the minimum width of my table with CSS.

I have tried shaving as much space as possible but I can't seem to make my tables any smaller for mobile.

(mobile site [go to bottom of the page and select mobile version]) http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-j1-white-deals/

Tables in question are in the tabs. Try resizing the page width in your browser as small as possible and you will see the problem.

As you can see in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpkIA.png) page is able to resize past tables minimum width.

Comment: Can you provide a simple self contained example of the problem? You can use the snippet feature `<>` to embed an example in your question. Make it as easy as us as you can for us to help you. Providing a link to a site you are currently fixing is a moving target. If you make a change how do we know you fixed it? Once it is fixed this question becomes useless to future users.

Comment: I don't think I could replicate the problem to be honest

Comment: just to be clear, inlcude problem using Screen shot. thanks

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/1uGqt9qU.png As you can see in the image, page is able to resize past tables minimum width.

Comment: Because table can't be smaller than it's contents. You can make content smaller or you can wrap your table with DIV with `overflow-x: auto` style (in this case horizontal scrollbar will be just on table and other parts of page will be on screen - see [bootstrap's responsive table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)). Describe the desired behaviour. What you want to see in cases when table contents really wider than device width?

Comment: if you want to achieve that, try to make a smaller font size, and the width of `td`'s

Comment: this problem does not occur on a phone with the same width screen with android the problem is safari mobile how can I set a minimum page width to the entire site - so even when safari is used it is forced to display all the data?

Comment: I'll repeat: you can't fit an elephant in a box. If content is wider than device screen width, how can it be forced to fit without a scroll? Scale? If this "problem" doesn't occur on android, then your andorind screen is just wider (in pixels) or page content is scaled down. You can't just go and violate the laws of physics. So you should just do a workaround: smaller font size, replace table with responsive floating divs to transform each table column to separate row when device is small etc.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to scale it respective to the screen unless you want to manually change the size of things and how they're laid out.

Comment: I fit the elephant into the iPhone 5C screen :P I found a few more pixels I could shave off the padding between the table cells I didn't manage to take it fully to the minimum width of the theme but I don't think there are many devices out there with a screen width smaller than the 5C

Answer (score 1):

This prevents the table content from bursting beyond the confines of its parent container, as in your screenshot.

```
#upgrades-datatable_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

*Screen sized to about 300 pixels*

Comment: neat little work around, i did manage to shave a few more pixels and make it fit neatly into an iPhone 5C screen but this code may still come in handy thanks :)